# Is this sentence “Horses are a useful animal.” correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english

I know a lot of people would say the correct sentence is “Horses are **useful animals**.”

But I think we can say “Computers are **an important research tool**.”, so I think we can say  “Horses are **a useful animal**.”

Am I wrong? Please explain.

Comment: Horse is a kind of useful animal.

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing like with like. Here is one pair

> Computers are useful tools.
>
> Horses are useful animals.

and here is another

> Computers are an important research tool.
>
> Horses are an important means of transport.

Although the statements about horses are not necessarily true today.

Comment: Hello Vane, I know that the first pair subject(Computers, Horses) is plural and object(useful tools, useful animals) is plural as well. But what I want to ask is why the second pair subject(Computers, Horses) is plural and object(an important research tool, an important means of transport) is singular?

Comment: Because of the generalisation. Computers (in general) are important. The 4th is clearer because "transport" is a singular word anyway.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what is difference between (1) [ Subject(plural) + are + Object(plural) ] and (2) [ Subject(plural) + are + a/an Object(singular) ]?

Comment: I don't know, I am not a formal grammar teacher.

Comment: "Computers are important research tools." Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do you know what difference between "Computers are important research tools." and "Computers are an important research tool."?

Comment: They mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot write a sentance like that - you are mixing up the plural "Horses" with the singular: "a ... animal"

Either Horses must become singular, such as "The Horse species", or else the final part must be plural too, or perhaps: "Horses are useful."

Comment: Can anyone explain why this answer was downvoted?